# SceneDelegate vs AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiapplicationdelegate, uiscenedelegate

Hi I want to check if the user use AppDelegate or SceneDelegate
as I want to swizzle functions like  `DidBecomeActive`, so how to check it? I was thinking of checking this by detecting if the user use `Application Scene Manifest` in the info.plist, Can anyone help me with this or provide me with a better solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DonMag this is not like the question above, I want to be able to check which one the user use?

Comment: OK - you need to explain a bit more about what you're trying to do. You want to *"check if the user uses ..."* -- does that mean you're writing a library? Perhaps show a function you want to *swizzle* and how you are trying to do it to begin with.